# Display amount as currency with fractions only when currency type has fractions

Tags: angular, typescript

I use this code to display amount:

```
 <td>{{transaction.amount}} {{transaction.currency}}</td>
```

Currently I have this output: 56030 USD

Something like:

```
<td [ngSwitch]="transaction.currency">
 <span *ngSwitchCase="'JPY'">/// Display 1000 JPY</span>
 <span *ngSwitchCase="'USD'">/// Display 10.00 USD</span>
 <span *ngSwitchDefault class="badge">/// Display 10.00 USD</span>
</td>
```

How I can add .00 based on currency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can alter the way you do it now a bit to achieve what you want:

```
<td *ngIf='transaction.currency=="JPY"'>{{transaction.amount|number:'1.0-0'}} {{transaction.currency}}</td>

<td *ngIf='transaction.currency!=="JPY"'>{{transaction.amount|number:'1.2-2'}} {{transaction.currency}}</td>
```

The first pipe "|number:'1.2-2'" will format it as number, with 2 fraction after the dot, and the other section is just text from your transaction object

A bit better solution as suggested is

```
<td>{{ transaction.amount | currency:transaction.currency:'' }} {{ transaction.currency }}</td>
```

or if you don't mind the currency code on the left side you can use:

```
<td>{{ transaction.amount | currency:transaction.currency:'code' }}</td>
```

Comment: I get 5,000,000 USD. Any idea why there are no cents?

Comment: I get Error: InvalidPipeArgument: 'digitsInfo.match is not a function' for pipe 'DecimalPipe'

Comment: sry was reffering to angularjs, this is for angular

Comment: Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: what are you expecting to get?

Comment: For Japan currency there should be no cents: 505 JPY

Comment: so you can use a fancy switch case, or simple ngIf like @Saksham answer

Comment: But I have 40+ currencies. I can't use so big switch case.

Comment: you only need two -> one case for currencies without fractions, and another for currency with fraction. If only JPY has no fraction than u are good with what I wrote

Comment: What about this:                 `<td>{{ transaction.amount | currency:transaction.currency:'' }} {{ transaction.currency }}</td>`

Comment: Do you know better alternative? Looks ugly.

Comment: hmm, what about this:<td>{{ transaction.amount | currency:transaction.currency:'code' }} </td>

Comment: I get USD56,030.00 which is incorrect. Places should be switched.

Comment: xD then no other way.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't necessarily answer your question, but have you considered using the built in currency Pipe?

https://angular.io/api/common/CurrencyPipe

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using the in-built currency pipe as

```
<td [ngSwitch]="transaction.currency">
     <span *ngSwitchCase="'JPY'">
        {{ transaction.amount | currency:'JPY':'symbol':'1.0-0'}}
     </span>
     <span *ngSwitchCase="'USD'">
        {{ transaction.amount | currency:'USD':'symbol':'1.2-2'}}
     </span>
     <span *ngSwitchDefault class="badge">
        {{ transaction.amount | currency:'USD':'symbol':'1.2-2'}}
     </span>
</td>
```

The last attribute to the currency pipe filter depicts the digits info in format

```
{minIntegerDigits}.{minFractionDigits}-{maxFractionDigits}
```

Here the US currency will have atleast one integer digit with minimum and maximum of 2 digits whereas Japanese currency will have no fractions

Comment: You may want to change transaction.currency to transaction.amount while applying pipe.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way just to display the currency with fractions (.00) But with the 3 characters for currency type? I don't need $10,080.00 I need 10,080.00 USD

Answer (score 0):

Try to use currency filter:

```
<td>{{transaction.amount | currency: transaction.currency}}</td>
```

Comment: I don't need `$10,080.00` I need `10,080.00 USD`. Do you know how to get this result?

Comment: Any idea how to implement it?