# Display the currency with fractions

Tags: angular, typescript

I use this code to display amount using the built in currency Pipe:

```
<td>{{transaction.amount | currency: transaction.currency}}</td>
```

Is there a way just to display the currency with fractions (.00) with the 3 characters for currency type? I don't need `$10,080.00` I need `10,080.00 USD` or `10080 JPY`

Is there a wya to get this visual result?

Comment: How is this different from [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55817091/display-amount-with-cents)?

Comment: Have you read [the docs](https://angular.io/api/common/CurrencyPipe), as has already been suggested to you?

Comment: please delete this. I've answered in your original post.

Answer (score 0):

See Currency Pipe documentation on [Angular.io](https://angular.io/api/common/CurrencyPipe)

Add the following after the transaction.currency

> :'code'

Ex:

{{10000 | currency: 'USD':'code'}}

Your amount will need to be in a number format and separated from the currency in order for this to work properly.  If your transaction.amount has "$" in it, then you'll need to modify the payload to have it removed and send the correct currency separately.

Ex: { amount: 10000, currency: 'USD' }

Unfortunately, In the US, USD is inserted at the beginning and without a space like this: USD10,000.00.  You'll have to live with this if you go with the build in Angular solution.  Otherwise, if you want to show the USD with a space and at the end, you'll have to create your own pipe and override the output of the currency pipe.

Comment: What about this: <td>{{transaction.amount|number}} {{transaction.currency}}</td>?

Comment: this assumes that all currencies will be shown AFTER the amount, which isn't the case globally

Comment: Yes, But I need it this way.